# How can I get Visual Studio's "Create method stub" or "Declare method" refactoring in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, plugins, ide, refactoring

When I code in Delphi XE and need a new procedure/function in another unit (for example on a datamodule) then I miss the Visual Studio feature where I can just type the new method name and use the "Create method stub" feature:

[image: Example in Visual Studio]

or using CodeRush the "Declare method" refactoring:

[image: CodeRush example]

I prefer this TDD style development as it is faster than first switching to the data module for example, navigating to the interface section and creating the procedure/function myself there.

Do anybody know how I can achieve that in Delphi XE using plugins/add-ins etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Model Maker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) is what you need. I use this all the time - various ways to trigger it, but it will take the parameters that you have in your code and work out what they should be, then create the template code. You can also define all sorts extra, but MMX is the business for this sort of thing.

Comment: I've downloaded the MMX trail, it looks promising but seems as if it only can create the procedure in the current unit? See for example http://imgur.com/iiptS . It does not detect that I want to create the new method in the TdmMain class? Might I be missing something?

Comment: @Kobus Email their support, they are very responsive. There's such a lot there that it might do it in other units too - I don't know as I am always wanting to add it to the current class.

Comment: I've mailed the MMX support team and they were very responsive indeed:

Comment: >>Can the MMX "Add method" create the new procedure/function in an unit other
than the current unit?<< 
No, only in the current module.
  >>Do you plan such a feature?That would be really useful and speed up my development<<  

Cross file editing has been requested in other cases too, but is a completely new area.
Will check what can be done.But the main problem in the case you provided is that MMX does not automatically detect to which class the method should be added.It does not compile code.Add Method uses current method as class context to add the new method. 
Gerrit Beuze ModelMaker Tools

Comment: MMX does seems to be a very useful Delphi add-on, I'm already hooked on the "Sync Declaration/Implementation" function! It just take a while to resolve the shortcut key clashes with GExperts and CnPack.

Answer (score 1):

RAD Studio is not Visual Studio. AFAICT, RAD Studio does not have such a feature. The only thing that comes close is class completion, but then you'll have to declare the method in the interface first. There is something like it for variables, but not for methods.

Comment: Yes I know RAD Studio is not Visual Studio :)
I was a Delphi programmer for years and then .NET programmer for a few years and now I'm doing a Delphi contract and I enjoy it but miss some useful functionality. Don't you think something like that would be useful?

Comment: Sure it would be useful. I am just describing how it is, not how it should be. <g>

Answer (score 1):

May be you can take a look at [castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/delphi-refactoring.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Castalia again but could not achieve that functionality the last time I checked. This specific (basic IMHO) refactoring is not on their list.